# Angular set base href for different static landing pages

Tags: angular

My folder structure:

```
 /LandingPage1/
                css/
                images/
                page1.html
                page2.html
                index.html
 /LandingPage2/
                css/
                images/
                page1.html
                page2.html
                index.html
 /LandingPage3/
                css/
                images/
                page1.html
                page2.html
                index.html
 index.html
```

To /index.html I added:

```
 <base href="/">
<script>
  (function() {
    window['_app_base'] = '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
  })();
</script>

<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Also in angular.json the position of that index.html was changed.

And in app.module:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window['_app_base'] || '/' },
  ]
```

I would like to:

when I open in browser `localhost:4200/LandingPage1` <- I will access to those page1, page2, etc.

Byt when I changed to `localhost:4200/LandingPage2` -> I will can open /LandingPage2/page1.html

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this add all your static path in assets section under angular.json file

```
"assets": [
"src/LandingPage1",
"src/LandingPage2",
"src/LandingPage3",
]
```

After changes run the ng serve command again then you will be able to access the static pages inside these folder.

Please follow the link for complete guide:[click here](https://codinghub.net/article/angular-static-page-setup)

Comment: Thank You, I added it and have the error: ```Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'page1.html'```

Comment: another simple way is to move your static page inside the assets folder then you can access all your pages but in that case URL will be  localhost:4200/assets/LandingPage2/page1.html

Comment: Thank you. But how we can do that without /assets/ path?

Comment: I have modified my answer please follow that to do it without assets path